# ajax call xhr shows 100% before the code reaches success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am implementing an ajax progress bar, but the xhr shows 'Uploading 100%' instantly, even though ajax success function is still not called.

```
    $.ajax({

                data: //data,
                type: 'post',
                url: url,                
                async: false,
                xhr: function() {
                        xhr: function() {
                             var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                             xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                                 if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                    console.log(percentComplete);
                                    $('#status').html('<b> Uploading -> ' + (Math.round(percentComplete * 100)) + '% </b>');
                                }
                            }, false);
                            return xhr;
                        },
        },
        success: // code


  };
```

Comment: Presumably, the request completed without being successful.

Comment: `async: false,` — This is deprecated and awful. Don't do that.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your response. Request is always successful. When I click the upload button, it instantly shows percentComplete 100% and after 1 minute, the success function is called.